# error ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I want to upload image with GridJS. I am using https://www.npmjs.org/package/gridfs-stream for this. It gives me `error` `ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined`.

I am beginner to this, so have no idea whats going.

How to solve this error?

```
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
    var conn = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'Test', 27017);
    var gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose);

    var fileId = new ObjectID(uniqId);
    var fileType = req.header('X-File-Type');
    var fileName = req.header('X-File-Name');
    var uniqId = req.param('uniqId', '112211112111');

    console.log('upload start');
    // streaming to gridfs
    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream(fileId, [{ "content_type": fileType, "metadata": { "fileName": fileName, "uploaded_at": (new Date()).toString() } }]);
    fs.createReadStream('/some/path').pipe(writestream);

    // streaming from gridfs
    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream(fileId, [{ "content_type": fileType, "metadata": { "fileName": fileName, "uploaded_at": (new Date()).toString() } }]);

    //error handling, e.g. file does not exist
    readstream.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('An error occurred!', err);
        throw err;
    });

    readstream.pipe(response);
    console.log('upload done');
```

Comment: what's this var fileId = new ObjectID(uniqId); I don't see any uniqId in the code

Comment: ohhh....i added it later....also the error got solved....but a new error says `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 25):

`ObjectID` is not a global variable, it is defined by mongoose (see the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)):

```
var fileId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

Answer (score 15):

Try This. It'll work in your code properly.

```js
// ObjectID deprecated ❌
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

```js
// ObjectiD ✅
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
```

Comment: TypeError: ObjectId is not a constructor ❌

Answer (score 7):

```js
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
```

ObjectID (with capital "D") is deprecated. Use ObjectId (lowercase "d") instead. (source: @types/bson package

Answer (score 6):

You can use the below code to get the `ObjectId`

```js
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
```

If you want to use it

```js
db.collection.deleteOne({_id: new ObjectId(req.params._id)})
.then(data => {
  res.send({status: "Success", data});
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For mongoose version 7 you can use `mongoose.ObjectId`. For example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  likes: {
    type: [mongoose.ObjectId],
    default: [],
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('card', cardSchema);
```